# Micronaut - better logging of issues

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-client

So, I'm trying to diagnose a problem with a simple ID change for a Id such as:

```
@Client(id = "zooClient")
```

which is located in a library ("Jar").   This should be super simple, but so far, I've been unable to get it working.   I turned on the trace level logging hoping that it would finger the issue, but so far I get output such as:

*{"@timestamp":"2023-05-26T15:52:28.278Z","ecs.version":"1.2.0","log.level":"DEBUG","message":"Bean [com.zooapolis.$ZooClientAdaptor$Definition] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:","process.thread.name":"main","log.logger":"io.micronaut.context.condition.Condition"}*

which isn't very helpful as I realize that it failed, but it doesn't help determine *why* it failed.   Most likely like the 'ZooClient' (which has the actual Id change) isn't loading which is why the 'ZooClientAdaptor' Bean can't be loaded, but there is nothing in the logs about the ZooClient.

Are there better diagnostics?   So far, simple inspection from pre-change and the change is giving me no help as it appears correct.

I have these currently:

```
    <logger name="io.micronaut.http.client" level="trace"/>
    <logger name="io.micronaut.context" level="trace"/>
    <logger name="io.micronaut.context.condition" level="trace"/>
```

Thanks in advance as any help appreciated.